# Does Google Custom Search API returm ads data?

Tags: json, web-applications, google-api, google-custom-search

Is it possible to get **google ads** data with Google Custom Search API?

For example, is this possible if someone enters an input like "Cricket bats", all the ads running on that keyword show? Is this possible to embed this function in a custom application?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Custom Search API does not return ads.

You may wish to consider Custom Search Ads, which are available on Web, Android, and iOS: https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads